# Prepare a dataset in Excel then import to Mathematica

Tags: import, dataset, excel

I need to prepare a dataset, which will be much easier using e.g. Excel. Then I want to import and use it in Mathematica. One row in the dataset would look like this in Mathematica:

```
{"A2",{"a2","b3"},"K6",{"a6","b2"}}
```

When doing this in Excel, it would look like this.

[image]

However, importing this into Mathematica produces:

```
{"A2","{"a2","b3"}","K6","{"a6","b2"}"}
```

The problem is the curly brackets, which get some extra quotation mark. I need these curly brackets in several columns. Using a combination of ToExpression and then back to ToString becomes very clumsy, in particular as during such a procedure a2 gets a space in between etc. Ideally, I'd like to import it as typed in Excel. I tried various cell formats in Excel without success. I also could not find a way in Mathematica for a plain import. Even exporting and then importing it as .csv doesn't get rid of this.

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't actually be much more expedient to generate the dataset in Mathematica directly. Is there an algorithmic rule that generates each row?

Comment: What is the final output you're expecting? Something like this? 

`{"A2",{"a2","b3"},"K6",{"a6","b2"}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, when importing the `xlsx` file you get rather something like :

`xsl={{{"A2", "{a2,a3}", "K6", "{a6,b2}"}}};`

and basically what you need is only to transform strings like `"{a2,a3}"` to a list of strings `{"a2","a3"}`.

[String manipulation functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StringManipulation.html) can help. Here is a solution:

```
xsl /. x_String?(StringMatchQ["{*}"]) :> StringSplit[StringTake[x, {2, -2}], ","]
```

> `{{{"A2", {"a2", "a3"}, "K6", {"a6", "b2"}}}}`

Comment: Great! However ... I was wondering if this is also possible within a dataset. Say, there are many xs1, then xs2, then xs3, ... Then two columns contain "{a2,a3}" in each row. Now I'd like to apply your function to the entire column, so that in the dataset the column contains the "{a2,a3}" correctly. I tried a few things from the 'dataset' help menu, but was not successful.

Comment: @MockupDungeon Minimal example: `ds = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> "{1}"|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> "{2,3}"|>}]; ds[All, {"c" -> (# /. 
      x_String?(StringMatchQ["{*}"]) :> 
       StringSplit[StringTake[x, {2, -2}], ","] &)}]`. The "c" column has been transformed. Read the [Dataset docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html).

Comment: Thanks! Tried something very similar, but made some minor mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Using a .xlsx file with the data pictured below:

```
data = Import["thedata.xlsx"];
Flatten[data,2]
```

Should produce:

```
{A2, {a2,b3}, K6, {a6,b2}}
```

Are you not getting a similar result?

[image: Excel data]

Comment: You are being tricked by the way strings are shown in the output. Try `Flatten[data, 2] // InputForm` to see what is really being imported, which is equivalent to the problem in the OP.

Comment: It is tricky, but I get something slightly different from the OP:
{"A2", "{a2,b3}", "K6", "{a6,b2}"}, 
I don't see quotes around the elements of the inner lists.

Comment: I agree with you on the last point. I suspect that the OP has misplaced their quotes when copy/pasting, since the pattern they indicated is unlikely. Nevertheless, what you get is still not what they want, unfortunately.

Comment: @Lee it just looks right but unfortunately isn't, as will be seen when executing the output. I probably have the quotes because of a different input format in Excel. The main problem is the quotation marks around the entire cell content (e.g. "{a2,b3}") which I cannot get rid of.

Comment: @MockupDungeon Yes, I learned that after following the suggestion from MarcoB.  I tried many, many different methods with Import and SemanticImport, but nothing imports the lists properly.